# React-router routes with parameters not loading properly when link are hardcoded to the URL bar

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am creating a hospital appointment system using React Js when I encountered some problems with react-router-dom. When I clicked on the link or a button, I would be properly redirected to the expected page. However, when I tried to copy the exact link on the URL tab and re-run it in a new tab or even just reload it, the page is not working properly, the designs are off, the pictures are gone, but the descriptions are still there. Any ideas why these problems are occurring? Here is a snippet of my code

main.js

```
function App() {
  const userSignin = useSelector((state)=>state.userSignIn);
  const {userInfo} = userSignin;
  const history = useHistory()
   const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const signoutHandler = () =>{
        dispatch(signout());
        history.push("/");
    }; 
    

  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">
          <div id="wrapper">
              <nav className="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                  <div className="top-area">
                    <div className="container">
                      <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                          <p className="bold text-left">Monday - Saturday, 8am to 10pm </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                          <p className="bold text-right">Call us now +62 008 65 001</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="container navigation">
                      <div className="navbar-header page-scroll">
                        <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                          data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                          <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </button>
                        <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/"><span className="medi">MEDI</span><span className="call">CALL</span>
                        </Link>
                      </div>

                      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
                        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                          <li className="active top"><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                          <li className="top"><Link to="/#service">Service</Link></li>
                          <li className="top"><Link to="/#doctor">Doctors</Link></li>
                          <li className="top"><Link to="/#facilities">Facilities</Link></li>
                          {userInfo ? (
                            <li className="dropdown top">
                            <Link to="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span className="badge custom-badge red pull-right"></span>Welcome {userInfo.data[1]} <b className="caret"></b></Link>
                            <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><Link to="/appointments">Appointments</Link></li>
                              <li><Link to="/createAppointment">Request Appointment</Link></li>
                              <li><Link to="#">Transactions</Link></li>
                              <li><Link to="#">Medicines</Link></li>
                              <li className="top"><Link to="/onlineres">Online Result</Link></li>
                              <li > <Link onClick={signoutHandler} className="dropdown-item" >Sign Out</Link></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          ):(
                            <li className="top"><Link to="/signin">Sign In</Link></li>
                          )}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                  
                  </div>
                </nav>
                
        </div>
    </div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/signin' component={UserTypeSignIn}></Route>
            <Route exact path='/signin/:user' component={SignIn}></Route>
            <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
            <Route path ="/medhistory" component={MedicalHistory}/>
            <Route path ="/appointments" component={AppointmentPage}/>
            <Route path ="/onlineres" component={Results}/>
            <Route path="/createAppointment" component={CreateAppointmentSlip}/>
            <Route path="/dentistryquestions" component={DentistQuestions}/>
            <Route path="/obgynequestions" component={OBquestionScreen}/>
            <Route path="/medicalcard" component={MedicalCardScreen}/>
            <Route path="/optalquestions" component={OptalQuestionsScreen}/>
            <Route path="/generalHealthquestions" component={GeneralHealthScreen}/>
            <Route path = "/">
                <Intro/>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
 <BrowserRouter>
);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Send the code of `SignIn` component.

Comment: Please update your question to include a more complete and comprehensive code example so that we can see how you are rendering a `Router` component and all the routes, to the component rendering the `Link` component, and all components between?

Comment: Hi! I updated my post on the code @DrewReese

Comment: Hi! I updated my post on the code @davoodSandoghsaz

Comment: Are you rendering more than one router? Is there one wrapping `App` to provide a routing context for the `useHistory` hook?

Comment: Yes sir, I am rendering more than one router. The app is the homepage of my website.

Comment: You need only one router for the entire app. Try removing all the extraneous routers, all but the highest one wrapping your app component.

Comment: I enclosed only the main code with the BrowserRouter component. I have multiple Route since I have different pages that I want to render